# uib-datepicker-popup: calendar displays, button bar buttons function properly, but day buttons do not

Tags: angular-bootstrap

I'm using uib-datepicker-popup fairly heavily in my application. It has worked perfectly until this specific instance.

I am using it exactly the same as I have in every other instance of my application, but it only half works.

The "Today", "Clear" and "Done" buttons in the bottom bar work as expected (hitting "today" puts the date in the input and hides the calendar, "clear" clears the input and hides the calendar, "done" hides the calendar).

However, when I select any date/day on the calendar it highlights it, but the date does not populate in the input and the calendar remains open.

Here's my html:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="convert_date" uib-datepicker-popup="M/d/yyyy" ng-model="vm.case.convert_date" ng-disabled="!vm.isActive" placeholder="m/d/yyyy" is-open="open" ng-click="open = true" ng-focus="open = true" show-weeks="false">
```

Any ideas why the date buttons won't populate the input?

Comment: I can't edit my post, but this appears to have something to do with the specific angular view. The exact html can be pasted in other locations within my application and works perfectly. This is likely something that will not be easy for someone else to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

**ngModelOptions** was the culprit here. I had it set for the entire view in this area of my application as follows:

```js
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur click', debounce: {'blur': 0, 'click': 0} }"
```

This prevented the day/date buttons from being able to fire their events and populate the input and hide the calendar.

I resolved my problem by adding another instance of ngModelOptions directly as an attribute to my uib-datepicker-popup element like so:

```html
<input ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default' }" name="convert_date" uib-datepicker-popup="M/d/yyyy" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.case.convert_date" ng-disabled="!vm.isActive" placeholder="m/d/yyyy" is-open="open" ng-click="open = true" ng-focus="open = true" show-weeks="false">
```

This reset the model behavior to the default settings, so that the datepicker could function properly again.